# Creating symlinks in "~/Library/Application Support/minecraft" that point to Dropbox, but "the original item for "[file]" can’t be found."

Tags: finder, macos, dropbox, symlink

The Background:
I use Dropbox to back up my minecraft worlds, configuration files, and various other folders (bin, launcher_profiles.json, mods, resourcepacks, saves, servers.dat, versions).
I put symbolic links in "~/Library/Application Support/minecraft" which point to the files and folders in Dropbox.

The Problem:
Ever since I upgraded to Yosemite, the symbolic links don't work anymore, giving the error "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “[file]” can’t be found."
I can't think of any reason that the links wouldn't work anymore. Any help appreciated.

Running:
Dropbox 3.0.3
Mac OS X v10.10.1
Minecraft Launcher 1.5.3
Minecraft 1.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correction:** 'sudo' was not the problem. I was using a bash script to link all the files automatically, which for some reason ends up creating symlinks that point to where they are created ('source file' is ignored and substituted with 'target file').

[image: Screenshot of the 'target as source' problem]

Basically what you end up with is a file that points to itself.

This problem doesn't happen when you type the command into the Terminal manually for each file. You also have to specify the full path to the file you are linking, which I didn't think I needed to. Not sure why, might be a bug with bash or OS X or whatever.

So, instead of:

```
ln -s saves ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/saves
```

type (manually in Terminal):

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/path/to/saves ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/saves
```

Hope this helps anyone who is having the same problem.

Comment: That's odd. You shouldn't need a symlink made by `root` (what happens when you `sudo ln`) here. It's all in directories you own.

Comment: I agree, made no sense. Also, notice corrections.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't in `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/` instead of `~/Dropbox/path/to/`?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure. The linking script that I used was only in Dropbox, and I CD'd into the directory manually when I ran the script. after the script failed, I then tried to link them manually from current directory as shown above under 'instead of'.

Comment: I also just got the idea that the link might also with by putting './' in front of the file name when in the directory (i.e. 'ln -s ./saves ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/saves'), but I'll leave that up to someone else to test.